# How to get all items in a dropdown list

Tags: robotframework

I think this should be a simple issue but I have a dropdown of a random amount of labels and I need to get all the labels out of it.

I've tried using "Get Selected List Labels" keyword but it only gets the first/visible value. I could try a loop but I don't know how to get the length of the list as it can be random.

```
click element    //*[@id="shortName0"]
${validate_mx_shortnms}=    Get Selected List Labels    //*[@id="shortName0"]
```

Ideally I want to put all the values in a list so I can use it for further comparisons. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should copy your random label into an array in a loop (check whether label exist in new array or not) and print that array.

Comment: @AbhishekYadav how do I get the length of the list to stop the loop? I believe I can only use a for loop in robotframework.

Answer (score 1):

Actually discovered the Get List Items keyword which does what I want instead.

`${validate_mx_shortnms}=    Get List Items    //*[@id="shortName0"]`